# How to fix the image background if the web page is scrollable

Tags: css, ios, xhtml, uiwebview

I have a web page which is scrollable, i need to make the image background fixed so that it doesn't repeat when i scroll, i try this :

```
<body style="background:url(background.png);background-attachement: fixed;">
```

The image is displayed but it's repeated when the web page is scrollable which make it ugly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `background-repeat:no-repeat;`.  Also depending on your situation you might have to add a `!important` modifier at the end of the rule. Check Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bhbAv/ .  If that doesn't work for you don't forget to add the `!important` at the end.

Comment: when i make it `background-repeat:no-repeat;` the image doesn't repeat but it moves with the scroll. However, in my case i need to make the image fixed and all the text in the web page scrollable :)

Comment: Check this page out: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background-attachment

Answer (score 2):

You should really do this all in one statement too where possible, such as:

```
<body style="background:url(background.png) no-repeat fixed;">
```

Comment: may be i should say that i use the iPhone browser which is Safari :), does that make difference?

Comment: `background-attachment:fixed;` Doesn't work on mobile safari. As `position:fixed;` or any fixed element. [Try workarounds.](http://doctyper.com/archives/200808/fixed-positioning-on-mobile-safari/)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for:

```
background-attachment:fixed;
```

You typed:

```
background-attach_E_ment: fixed;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes I agree, probably background-attachment:fixed; would do it.

Take a look at this: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp